# Ant build file skeleton to turn an eclipse project into a war?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

Does anyone have a skeleton build file that I can modify to war up an eclipse dynamic web project.

I need to war it up and make sure that all the libraries/servlets are in the right place.

Comment: ROFL! Upvoted for the hilarious title! :D

Comment: I hadn't thought of it that way...

Comment: Upvoted for the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating a deployable WAR file from Eclipse Project](http://arkblog.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/creating-a-deployable-war-file-from-eclipse-project/)

Answer (score 1):

[I'm going to be voted down because it doesn't *directly* answer your question, but alas...]

I am also using Eclipse WTP for my web projects but I want to keep my own structure (IMO code should be independent from the tools).  Fortunately, you can define where the various assets are located by modifying the project's `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file.